# How to get HAR from Selenium SafariDriver browser via browsermob-proxy?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, browsermob

I am trying to get HAR object from Safari driver. I have created a driver object via Selenium but when I am getting entries from the `har` object, it is empty. What is the issue? Who know how to get HAR from Selenium SafariDriver browser?

`...
    driver = new SafariDriver();  // Launching Safari Browser
    driver.navigate().to("http://....")  // opening some http web site 
    Har har = Driver.server.getHar();
    List<HarEntry> entries = (har.getLog()).getEntries(); // entries are empty`

Comment: Can you post what has been done by you?